# Selenium messes up xpaths

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

The website I am trying to scrape is 'https://www.lamiastampante.it/cerca_codice_cartuccia.php?codice=D111L&lg=it', and I am using python with Selenium for that.
I want to click on the title of the first product came out of my search.
It is an **a** element within a **div**, but when I copy the parent's XPath of such element (the 's XPath), my python script thinks I am referring to another (incorrect) element which is a pane located on the right of the webpage.
I noticed that because if I print out the class of the element gotten from that XPath I get "panel-heading", while it should be "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12".

This is my very short python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.lamiastampante.it")

driver.find_element(By.ID, "form_oem_code").send_keys("D111L" + Keys.ENTER)

first_product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]""")# XPath of the target's parent element.
# first_product.click() /Commented out because I should first get the <a> element within that contains the link that can be clicked.
```

You can go visit the web page and inspect its HTML structure. I had some hard times trying to copy paste it here in a comprehensive and useful manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the link after search results induce `WebDriverWait`() and ait for element_to_be_clickable() and following `xpath`.

```
driver.get("https://www.lamiastampante.it")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "form_oem_code").send_keys("D111L" + Keys.ENTER)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//a[starts-with(@id,'a_') and contains(.,'Toner')])[1]"))).click()
```

---

Or yon can use `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and below xapth.

```
driver.get("https://www.lamiastampante.it")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "form_oem_code").send_keys("D111L" + Keys.ENTER)
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[starts-with(@id,'a_') and contains(.,'Toner')]")))
elements[0].click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Can you please tell me why it was not working when I tried to click on that link using explicit wait and the element's XPath?```
first_product = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]'))
)
```
I was still getting the same problem.

Comment: @giuliodizio : you shouldn't use such `xpath` which is error prone.